# Is it possible to determine what is inside Debian package without installing it?

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude, markdown

I need a markdown library for development - based on package names I could not understand which one I should install...

```
den@playground:~$ sudo aptitude search markdown
p   html2markdown                                                          - convert HTML page into ascii markdown format
p   libhtml-wikiconverter-markdown-perl                                    - HTML to wiki markup converter - MoinMoin dialect
p   liblua5.1-markdown0                                                    - A pure lua5.1 implementation of the Markdown text-to-html markup
p   libmarkdown-php                                                        - PHP library for rendering Markdown data
p   libpod-markdown-perl                                                   - module to convert POD to the Markdown file format
p   libtext-markdown-perl                                                  - Markdown and MultiMarkdown markup languages library
p   libtext-multimarkdown-perl                                             - Perl module to convert MultiMarkdown syntax to (X)HTML
p   markdown                                                               - Text-to-HTML conversion tool
p   python-markdown                                                        - text-to-HTML conversion library/tool
```

Comment: You don't need `sudo` here, that's only needed when you change something on the system (e.g. install a package), not when you're just looking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`apt-file` can do this. Install it with aptitude, update the database (with `apt-file update`), and then list the contents with `apt-file list package`.

Also, all packages have a description which you can view with e.g. `aptitude show html2markdown`. If you don't have the aptitude command, you can use `apt-cache` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `apt-file`, you can also do this with `dpkg`:

```bsh
dpkg --contents somefile.deb
```

Also, if you need to search for a particular file in *any* package:

```bsh
dpkg-query -S file # just the file, or...
dpkg-query -S usr/lib/libsomelib.so # a bit more specific.
```

Comment: This does require, however, that you have already downloaded the package.

Answer (score 2):

If you start up `aptitude` without any arguments, you get a really nice curses-style user interface where you can search for the each package, and see lots of great information about what's in it.

For example, press `/` then enter `markdown` to move to the next package whose name contains `markdown`. Press `l` then enter `markdown` to limit the display to packages whose name contains `markdown`. Choose “Un-Limit Display” in the “Search” menu to remove the display filter, or press `l` then enter `~A` meaning “limit to all packages”.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the contents of packages (any distribution and architecture) at the web site [packages.debian.org : Search package directories](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages).

Step 1: Enter the package name in the Keyword box below "Search package directories", e.g. `slrn`. There is a choice of distribution, and a choice between searching on package names only (binary package names) and source package names. Say we select stable and search on binary packages.

Step 2. We obtain `slrn`, `slrnface`, `slrnpull`. Selecting slrn we then go to the list of files at the bottom right. Selecting amd64 we obtain [Filelist of package slrn in squeeze of architecture amd64](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/slrn/filelist).